# Triple integrals in cartesian and cylindrical coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration

Can someone tell me why the answers highlighted in red ( 12 and pi/2 ) are wrong and how can I find the correct answers? The rest are correct
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Just draft the projection on the $xy$ plane and you'll immediately see what's wrong. Consider that $x^2+y^2=8y$ can be written as $x^2+(y-4)^2=16$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it

Comment: Since the projection on the $xy$ plane is a circle with a diameter of 8, it can be easily shown that $0\leq y\leq 8$.

Comment: oh yeah you're right. what about the angle theta?

Comment: To cover the whole domain you need $0\leq\theta\leq \pi$.

Comment: why isn't 2*pi ?

Comment: is it because the circle doesn't go below the x axis?